# Accessing enum value in memcpy

Tags: c

I am trying to copy the value of enum to some array through memcpy. Before this i will be doing a state change of enum from 0 to 1. Then i am copying this enum value to my array. I observed that there is state change but the value is not copied into array.
Initial enum value is 0 i.e., INIT_STATE, then i change the value to DISASSOCIATE_STATE.

My array is data[9], where 0-7 bytes is the device_id and 8 is the tag_state.
State is when BLE communication happens between tag and mobile app, i give 1 in the custom characteristics from nRF connect app, the state should change to DISASSOCIATE. This is happening that i can check in switch case.

So, When that changes, i should update the state in array. For that i'm using memcpy.

memcpy should update the tag state i.e., 8th byte of data[9].

My enum is

```
typedef enum {
    INIT_STATE,
    DISASSOCIATE_STATE,
    ASSOCIATE_STATE,
    SET_CONFIG_STATE
}cmd_type;
```

This is defined in one file. I am accessing it using cmd_type state;
This is the memcpy  command I'm using,

```
memcpy(data[8],state+1, 1);
```

Why the value is not getting copied?

Comment: What is `data`? What is `state`? Where's your [mcve]? And what is the problem with the code you show? What problem is that `memcpy` call supposed to solve? Lastly, not forgetting that enumeration values are basically plain compile-time symbolic constants for *integer* values, why can't you just do simple assignment (as in `data[9] = state + 1`)?

Comment: `cmd_type` is an integer type. How should `data+1` be a suitable argument for a parameter expecting a pointer? Turn on your compiler warnings and take care of them.

Comment: Turn all compiler warnings on (I recommend at least `-Wall -Wextra`) and you will find the problem. Hint: `memcpy` requires two addresses.